# How to append a single value to a list created by list comprehension on a single line?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to see if it is possible to append a single value to a list created through list comprehension on the same line.

Edit: I am trying to do this with just the base python install. No imports.

The closest working example I have takes 2 lines.

```
my_list = ['P' * 20 for i in range(105//20)]
my_list.append('P' * (105 % 20))

print(*my_list, sep='\n')
```

I tried something like:

```
my_list = ['P' * 20 for i in range(105//20)].append('P' * (105 % 20))

print(*my_list, sep='\n')
```

But that results in a NoneType error due to `append()`.

So I am wonder if it is at all possible to pull this off in another way on the same line as we build the list?

Expected final result:

```
PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPPP
```

Comment: You want 105 Ps grouped into groups of 20, with the remainder in a row by itself? See the `grouper` recipe in the `itertools` documentation.

Comment: @chepner I was wanting to look for something pythonic without any imports. There is the `textwrap` import that does exactly what I want even easier but it is an imported method.

Comment: There's nothing unpythonic about importing a module from the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take slices from the string of 105 "P"s.

```
>>> [("P"*105)[i:i+20] for i in range(0, 105, 20)]
['PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP', 'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP', 'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP', 'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP', 'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP', 'PPPPP']
```

Though to avoid relying on the implementation to only create the 105-character string once, you should probably define it prior to the comprehension.

```
ps = "P" * 105
result = [x[i:i+20] for i in range(0, 105, 20)]
```

Using the `grouper` recipe from the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), you could write

```
result = [''.join(x) for x in grouper("P"*105, 20, '')]
```

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew this would be possible all within one list comprehension expression.

Answer (score 3):

`append` won't work since it modifies the list *in-place*. You could just add them:

```
['P' * 20 for i in range(105//20)] + ['P' * (105 % 20)]

['PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP',
 'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP',
 'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP',
 'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP',
 'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP',
 'PPPPP']
```

---

Although for what you're trying to do, I'd do something like:

```
ps = 105
n = 20 
rows, r = divmod(ps, n)

['P'*n]*rows + ['P'*r]

['PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP',
 'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP',
 'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP',
 'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP',
 'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP',
 'PPPPP']
```

Comment: ... Its so simple I didnt even suspect I could use `+`... Got to love it when the simple things simply elude you. Thanks I will probably us this.